# change text color during Clint write in input field when specific char entered

Tags: javascript, html, css

i would like to change the color of the text the Clint writs in input filed based on a specific char for example, if the input type www.abcd.com and the char that activate the event is .(dot) the color will change like this: 
www.(in green)abcd.(in red)com(in yellow). i want the color to change twice every time time the specific char appears, because i expect it to heppear twice. 
here is the input filed i want the function to activate on`<input type="text" id="password_name"/>`i tryed `while` loop for `input filed. Length` to check  `if var char=="."{ 
//and than changed color
}`
but this is not working

Comment: You've told us what you'd like to happen, but you haven't told us what you've tried to achieve it... please read the [help] pages, in particular the [ask] section. What you're asking for sounds quite complex and I think you're going to struggle to get an answer that just involves a simple textbox

Comment: @Pete dont worry, the password itseld is set in input type password, this input filed is just for the websites name you are trying to save the password for.

Comment: @freefaller thank you, edited as you said to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe like this:

```js
function correct_color(_el){
 if(_el.value == 'www.'){
    _el.style.color = "green";
 }
 if(_el.value == 'www.abcd.'){
   _el.style.color = "red";
 }
 if(_el.value == 'www.abcd.com'){
   _el.style.color = "yellow";
 }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="password_name" onchange="correct_color(this);"  onkeyup="this.onchange();" onpaste="this.onchange();" oninput="this.onchange();"/>
```

Update:

Do not use input text...
Use DOM element with attribute contenteditable="true"

like this:

```js
function correct_color(_el){
 if(_el.value == 'www.'){
    _el.style.color = "green";
 }
 if(_el.value == 'www.abcd.'){
   _el.style.color = "red";
 }
 if(_el.value == 'www.abcd.com'){
   _el.style.color = "yellow";
 }
 var el_text = _el.innerText;
 var el_html = el_text.replace(new RegExp('www.','g'), '<span style="color: green">www.</span>');
 el_html = el_html.replace(new RegExp('abcd.','g'), '<span style="color: red">abcd.</span>');
 el_html = el_html.replace(new RegExp('com','g'), '<span style="color: yellow">com</span>');

 _el.innerHTML = el_html;

    var selection = window.getSelection();
    var range = document.createRange();
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    range.selectNodeContents(_el);
    range.collapse(false);
    selection.addRange(range);
    _el.focus();


}
```

```css
.cls-div-for-multicolor-edit{
 border-style:solid;
 border-width:1px;
 display:block;
 overflow:hidden;
 width:400px;
 height:18px;
 padding:2px;
}
```

```html
<code contenteditable="true" class="cls-div-for-multicolor-edit" onkeyup="correct_color(this);";></code>
```

Comment: but i dont want all the text to be change the color, just the part after the char that activate the fanction. also, www.abcd.com is just an exaple, the cling can incert ant input, onpaste is not vail as well. anothere proublem is the text disappirng after the input is finished

Answer (score -1):

Use javascript with onChange field in input tag for example :-
HTML Code

```
<input type="text" onChange="somefunction()" id="password_name"
  style="font-size:30px; color:black; position:relative; margin-right:20px;"/>
```

Use if statements according to the condition and change its style using:-

```
function somefunction(){
  object=document.getElementById('password_name')
}
```

Comment: Firstly, please learn how to [format code in your answers](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)... but secondly, how would you change the colour of specific characters in the value of the textbox?